# AsyncHttp not working in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-async-http

So i'm working on JSON,and i have an URL to get the JSON,but for some reason it says

> Connect to static-182-18-161-240.ctrls.in/218.93.250.18:7070 timed out

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ListView listView;
Response responseObj;
CustomAdapter adapter;
String url= "http://182.18.161.240:7070/sfaweb-1.1.015/get/retailers/dl-0004/2";
Gson gson;
AsyncHttpClient client;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.rtlist);
    client = new AsyncHttpClient();
    client.get(MainActivity.this, url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler() {


        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] responseBody) {
            String responsestr = new String(responseBody);
            gson = new Gson();
            responseObj = gson.fromJson(responsestr, Response.class);
            adapter = new CustomAdapter(MainActivity.this, responseObj);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

This is my code..I've added internet permissions in Manifest as well..
Help would be deeply appreciated..

Comment: make sure the internet is fine.

Comment: @Freddy everything is fine,even used a live phone to check out and the result is same